# Having trouble adding reactions discord.Js

Tags: discord.js

I want to make a confessions bot where it sends the confession to a private group so it can be reviwed before it is set to the public channel. but when I try to add reactions(to use as aprove or disaprove) it seams to want to add the reactions to the message that was deleted.

```js
const discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'confessions',
    description: "comando para as pesoas confessarem anonimamente",
    
    execute(message, args){
        let cf = args.join(' ')
    message.dlete()
        const cfAdm = message.guild.channels.cache.get('767082831205367809')
        let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('**CONFISSÃO**')
        .setDescription(cf)
        .setColor('#000000')
        cfAdm.send(embed);
      
        message.react('').then(r => {
            message.react('');
    });
   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```js
cfAdm.send(embed);

message.react('').then(r => {
                message.react('');
```

to

```js
cfAdm.send(embed)
.then( function (message) {
     message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));
```

And you also made a typo with `message.dlete()` it needs to be `message.delete()`